# Value from node in XML data type SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table(dbo.Orders with 2 fields: Id (int) and OrderItem(xml).

XML in the OrderItem field:

> ```
> <Placement>
>   <Position />
>   <SeriesTotal>1</SeriesTotal>
>   <Series>1</Series>
>   <SectionId>193</SectionId>
> </Placement>
> ```

What I want is a SQL statement selecting Id and the value from the  node.

SELECT Id,SectionId FROM dbo.Orders

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query for Xml values and attributes from table in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method to get the nth SectionId:

```
SELECT  o.ID,
        SectionID = o.OrderItem.value('(Placement/SectionId)[1]', 'INT')
FROM    dbo.Orders AS o;
```