# Aggregation query over XML document using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML file with this structure:

```
<row>
    <id><timestamp>
    <some other fields>
 </row>
 <row>
    <id><timestamp>
    <some other fields>
 </row>
```

Several rows have the same `id` but differ in their timestamps.

I want to write a query that extracts the content of the XML into an SQL rowset such that for each `id` I will get the row with the latest timestamp.

So far, thanks to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server), I got to extract the row using:

```
SELECT T2.Row.query('.')
FROM   #xml_tmp_table
CROSS APPLY XML_TABLE.nodes('/xml_ROOT/section_of_interest') as T2(Row)
```

Now, according to SQL Documentation, reading a single column of data from XML row can be done by the [value()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   T2.Row.query('.').value("id_field", "int"),
   max( T2.Row.query('.').value("timestamp_field", "datetime")),
   T2.Row.query('.').value("data_field_1", "decimal(5,2)")),
   T2.Row.query('.').value("data_field_2", "int")),
   ...
   T2.Row.query('.').value("yet_another_data_field", "its_type"))
FROM #xml_tmp_table --or T2 maybe?
group by id_field
```

So I would get only the rows with the latest timestamp per `id` value.

Any hints for the right way to accomplish this?

Guess I have to save the result of the first query into a temporary table and apply the `value()` on its rows.

Comment: Try firts read data from XML and then do grouping `WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM @xml) SELECT * FROM cte GROUP BY ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract your values in a derived table and do the group by in the main query.

```sql
select T.id,
       max(T.timestamp) as timestamp
from (
     select R.X.value('(id/text())[1]', 'int') as id,
            R.X.value('(timestamp/text())[1]', 'datetime') as timestamp
     from dbo.YourTable as T
       cross apply T.X.nodes('/root/row') as R(X)
    ) as T
group by T.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95070/1)

Comment: @Zack, if an answer works for you, please click it as "accepted". Everybody will see, that the problem is solved and Mikael Erikson is happy about reputation points :-)