# In SQL, what do the parentheses in the 'as' clause mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some XML querying in SQL and in order to get the attributes of multiple sibling nodes I need to do the following query:

```
select 
    C.value('@attribute[1]', 'varchar(30)') 
from 
    tblData
cross apply 
    XmlFieldL.nodes('/Data/Children') as T(C)
```

By default the `[1]` only gives the first item, so the cross apply gets around that and will give me a list of the `@attribute` for each child node. Cool, works great.

My question is what is the syntax around the `T(C)`? It looks like a function of some kind at first glance, or some kind of grouping. I reference the C, but why is the T portion necessary? What does the syntax mean?

For reference, [this was the original problem/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server) and better describes it. I'm just trying to understand exactly what I'm doing here.

Comment: Pretty well explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is your derived table's alias.

`C` is the column name that is shredded from the `/Data/Children` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `.nodes()` call returns a "pseudo table" with a single column for each of the matched XML fragments.

That's what the `T` (for the pseudo table) and `C` (column in that pseudo table) refer to