# Fetch XML node value with namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have to get values of company node elements.I have tried all the
method to fetch data from the node but no luck. Below is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <CompanyInvoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Customer xmlns="http://t.service/CompanyServices/">
        <Company>
          <CompanyId>10001</CompanyId>
          <CoastalId>454564564564564564564564565465454546565555555</CoastalId>
          <CompanyFederalId>345345</CompanyFederalId>
          <CompanyName>Anytime Home</CompanyName>
          <CompanyAddress>Address1</CompanyAddress>
          <CompanyCity>TR</CompanyCity>
          <CompanyState>UT</CompanyState>
          <CompanyPostalCode>11</CompanyPostalCode>
          <CompanyCountry>IT</CompanyCountry>
          <CompanyTelephone>(999) 999-9999</CompanyTelephone>
        </Company>
        <CustomerId>33642</CustomerId>    
      </Customer>
      </CompanyInvoice>
```

TSQL Code:
I have simply tried with this, but not getting any updates

```
Declare @DATAXML xml ='<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <CompanyInvoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Customer xmlns="http://t.service/CompanyServices/">
        <Company>
          <CompanyId>10001</CompanyId>
          <CoastalId>454564564564564564564564565465454546565555555</CoastalId>
          <CompanyFederalId>345345</CompanyFederalId>
          <CompanyName>Anytime Home</CompanyName>
          <CompanyAddress>Address1</CompanyAddress>
          <CompanyCity>TR</CompanyCity>
          <CompanyState>UT</CompanyState>
          <CompanyPostalCode>11</CompanyPostalCode>
          <CompanyCountry>IT</CompanyCountry>
          <CompanyTelephone>(999) 999-9999</CompanyTelephone>
        </Company>
        <CustomerId>33642</CustomerId>    
      </Customer>
      </CompanyInvoice>'


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://t.service/CompanyServices/' as x)
Select
a.value('x:CompanyId[1]','nvarchar(50)') as CompanyId, 
a.value('x:CoastalId[1]','nvarchar(500)') as CoastalId, 
a.value('x:CompanyName[1]','nvarchar(500)') as CompanyName
From @DATAXML.nodes('/CompanyInvoice/Customer/Company')as a (a)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server

Comment: You need to introduce and use namespaces in your query. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces#using-with-xmlnamespaces-with-the-xml-data-type-methods

Comment: @Serg, i introduce namespace, but no luck

Comment: But you haven't mentioned `x` namespace in the `nodes` 
...nodes('CompanyInvoice/x:Customer/x:Company') ...

Comment: @Serg, Oh!!! silly mistake. Thanks to notify me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you have two options. 
1.Introduce and use namespaces properly. Pay attention  to namespaces scope.
2.Use a wildcard namespace (not recommended in production)

```
Declare @DATAXML xml = N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <CompanyInvoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Customer xmlns="http://t.service/CompanyServices/">
        <Company>
          <CompanyId>10001</CompanyId>
          <CoastalId>454564564564564564564564565465454546565555555</CoastalId>
          <CompanyFederalId>345345</CompanyFederalId>
          <CompanyName>Anytime Home</CompanyName>
          <CompanyAddress>Address1</CompanyAddress>
          <CompanyCity>TR</CompanyCity>
          <CompanyState>UT</CompanyState>
          <CompanyPostalCode>11</CompanyPostalCode>
          <CompanyCountry>IT</CompanyCountry>
          <CompanyTelephone>(999) 999-9999</CompanyTelephone>
        </Company>
        <CustomerId>33642</CustomerId>    
      </Customer>
      </CompanyInvoice>';


WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://t.service/CompanyServices/' as x)
Select
a.value('x:CompanyId[1]','nvarchar(50)') as CompanyId, 
a.value('x:CoastalId[1]','nvarchar(500)') as CoastalId, 
a.value('x:CompanyName[1]','nvarchar(500)') as CompanyName
From @DATAXML.nodes('CompanyInvoice/x:Customer/x:Company')as a (a);

-- 

select t.node.value('*:CompanyId[1]', 'int')
from @DATAXML.nodes('*:CompanyInvoice/*:Customer/*:Company') t(node);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, But why we don't use wild card in production

Comment: Generally xml comes from another loosely coupled system and we don't want any bad stuff entering our DB. As  namespaces are an essential part of the data exchange contract, we'd better strictly define them the way contract prescribes.

Answer (score 1):

Try This this just and other example

[REferThis for more info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/read-xml-file-in-sql-server-2008)

```
  DECLARE @foo XML

SELECT @foo = N'
<harrys>
    <harry>
        <fish>0.015000000000</fish>
        <bicycle>2008-10-31T00:00:00+01:00</bicycle>
        <foo>ü</foo>
    </harry>
    <harry>
        <fish>0.025000000000</fish>
        <bicycle>2008-08-31T00:00:00+01:00</bicycle>
        <foo>ä</foo>
    </harry>
</harrys>
'

SELECT
    CAST(CAST(y.item.query('data(fish)') AS varchar(30)) AS float),
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(y.item.query('data(bicycle)') AS char(25)), 10) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(y.item.query('data(foo)') AS varchar(25))
FROM
    @foo.nodes('/*') x(item)
    CROSS APPLY
    x.item.nodes('./*') AS y(item)

SELECT
    CAST(CAST(x.item.query('data(fish)') AS varchar(30)) AS float),
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(x.item.query('data(bicycle)') AS char(25)), 10) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(x.item.query('data(foo)') AS varchar(25))
FROM
    @foo.nodes('harrys/harry') x(item)

SELECT
    CAST(CAST(y.item.query('data(fish)') AS varchar(30)) AS float),
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(y.item.query('data(bicycle)') AS char(25)), 10) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(y.item.query('data(foo)') AS varchar(25))
FROM
    @foo.nodes('/harrys') x(item)
    CROSS APPLY
    x.item.nodes('./harry') AS y(item)
```

If this dosent work then
[Alternate Link](https://www.tangrainc.com/blog/2008/11/import-xml-file-to-sql-table/)

Comment: Thanks for response but this not help me to achieve my result. I have added my tsql code. Try to get values on those