# Parse XML data from a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I'm trying to put together a report for a badge program. Some the data for custom fields we created are stored in a single column in the table as XML.  I need to return a couple of the items in there to the report and am having a hard time getting the proper syntax to get it to parse out.

Aside from the XML, the query itself is simple:

```
    SELECT
  Person1.firstName
  ,Person1.lastName
  ,Person1.idNumber
  ,Person1.idNumber2
  ,Person1.idNumber3
  ,Person1.status
  ,Person1.customdata
FROM
  Person1
```

the field "customdata" is the XML field that I need to pull Title, and 2 different dates out of.  This is what the XML looks like:

```xml
    <person1_7:CustomData xmlns:person1_7="http://www.badgepass.com/Person1_7">
    <Title>IT Director</Title>
    <Gaming_x0020_Level>Level 1</Gaming_x0020_Level>
    <Gaming_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>2021-02-18T12:00:00Z</Gaming_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>
    <Gaming_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>2022-02-18T12:00:00Z</Gaming_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>
    <Betting_x0020_Level>Level 1</Betting_x0020_Level>
    <Betting_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>2021-02-18T12:00:00Z</Betting_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>
    <Betting_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>2022-02-18T12:00:00Z</Betting_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>
    <BadgeType>Dual Employee</BadgeType>
    <Gaming_x0020_Status>TEMP</Gaming_x0020_Status>
    <Betting_x0020_Status>TEMP</Betting_x0020_Status>
    </person1_7:CustomData>
```

I have tried a couple of different methods trying to follow the advice from  [How to query for Xml values and attributes from table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server)  and then tried declaring a XML namespace with the following query:

```
       WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.badgepass.com/Person1_7' as X)
SELECT
  Person1.firstName
  ,Person1.lastName
  ,Person1.idNumber
  ,Person1.idNumber2
  ,Person1.idNumber3
  ,Person1.status
  ,Person1.customdata.value('(/X:person1_7:customdata/X:Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Title
FROM
  Person1
```

So far all of my results keep returning "XQuery [Person1.customData.value()]: ")" was expected.
"  I'm assuming I have a syntax issue that I'm overlooking as I've never had to manipulate XML with SQL before.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- XQuery `.nodes()` method establishes a context so you can access any
  XML element right away without long XPath expressions.
- Use of the `text()` in the XPath expressions is for performance
  reasons.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @person1 TABLE (firstname varchar(50), customdata xml);
INSERT INTO @person1(firstname, customdata) VALUES
('John', '<person1_7:CustomData xmlns:person1_7="http://www.badgepass.com/Person1_7">
    <Title>IT Director</Title>
    <Gaming_x0020_Level>Level 1</Gaming_x0020_Level>
    <Gaming_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>2021-02-18T12:00:00Z</Gaming_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>
    <Gaming_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>2022-02-18T12:00:00Z</Gaming_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>
    <Betting_x0020_Level>Level 1</Betting_x0020_Level>
    <Betting_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>2021-02-18T12:00:00Z</Betting_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date>
    <Betting_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>2022-02-18T12:00:00Z</Betting_x0020_Expire_x0020_Date>
    <BadgeType>Dual Employee</BadgeType>
    <Gaming_x0020_Status>TEMP</Gaming_x0020_Status>
    <Betting_x0020_Status>TEMP</Betting_x0020_Status>
</person1_7:CustomData>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.badgepass.com/Person1_7' as person1_7)
SELECT firstName
  , c.value('(Title/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Title
  , c.value('(Gaming_x0020_Issue_x0020_Date/text())[1]', 'DATETIME') GamingIssueDate
FROM @person1
    CROSS APPLY customdata.nodes('/person1_7:CustomData') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+
| firstName |    Title    |     GamingIssueDate     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+
| John      | IT Director | 2021-02-18 12:00:00.000 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+
```